# On windows 7 - oauthtokengenerator.exe crashes after approval but before giving tokens

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I am trying to get the tokens from Google to proceed with development.

I downloaded adwords_dotnet_lib_v23.0.0 from Github, launched it, fed in client id and secret, got to Google login, logged in, approved app,
then `oauthtokengenerator.exe` stops working.

I did this up to 10 times on 2 separate Windows 7 computers.

I even disabled antivirus having already excluded the app folder from antivirus action.

Is this a bug? Is there a solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: I found this post that suggests it could be that port 8080 is already in use. http://adwords-api.narkive.com/v9aMMXQm/oauth2-token-generator-gives-access-is-denied